# Running multiple (i.e. normal and reversed) iterators simultaneously in a "for" loop

Tags: python, for-loop, iterator

Haven't found a satisfactory answer so far, hence posting this as a new question.

I have to do the following:

I have a parameter, e.g. `test_num = 5`.
Now, in a single iteration of a `for` loop, I want the iterator to run both forwards and backwards simultaneously.

So as an output, i want something like this:

```
Forward is 0, backward is 5.
Forward is 1, backward is 4.
Forward is 2, backward is 3.
Forward is 3, backward is 2. 
Forward is 4, backward is 1.
```

The only thing that i could think up of, is:

```
test_num = 5
for j in range(test_num):
    for i in range(test_num, 0, -1):
        print "Forward is ", i, ", Backward is ", j
```

But this is obviously not the right approach. Is using `zip` the only option? Because `zip` only works in case if i'm using the same parameter or in case of two parameters which are equal. I'm looking for something that's flexible enough.

Comment: What do you mean with "same parameter or in case of two parameters which are equal."? `zip` should work just fine.

Comment: Also, is it intentional that your "backwards" numbers are _not_ the forwards-numbers reversed but offset by 1?

Comment: It's not clear why you don't want zip, Can you explain with example

Comment: If i have two parameters, say `test_num1 = 5` and `test_num2 = 4`, `zip` stops as soon as the second iterator reaches 4.

Comment: @ tobias_k: yes, you're right. The "backwards" numbers are the forwards reversed and offset by 1.

Comment: I've added some benchmark for solutions. regards

Comment: Actually, it's my bad.. I was looking more for a "one size fits all" kind of solution. Both zip and the other solutions mentioned below work far too well for the situation at hand. I myself was confused for a bit. Sincere apologies guys..

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your code is pretty good but you only need 1 iterator.

```
for x in range(5):
    print(str(x)+'_'+str(5-x))
```

That will give you the right idea

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use two iterators, try using the `zip()` function:

```
for i,j in zip(range(5), range(5, 0, -1)):
    print "Forward is {0}, backward is {1}".format(i, j)
#Forward is 0, backward is 5.
#Forward is 1, backward is 4.
#Forward is 2, backward is 3.
#Forward is 3, backward is 2. 
#Forward is 4, backward is 1.
```

However, your particular use case seems easy enough to do using 1 iterator:

```
for i in range(5)
    print "Forward is {0}, backward is {1}".format(i, 5-i)
#Forward is 0, backward is 5.
#Forward is 1, backward is 4.
#Forward is 2, backward is 3.
#Forward is 3, backward is 2. 
#Forward is 4, backward is 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

fastest solution:

```
test_num = 5
for i in range(test_num):
    print("Forward is %d, backward is %d."%(i, test_num-i))
```

another fast solution(my solution if you wont use `test_num-i` expression) :

```
test_num = 5
for i,j in enumerate(range(test_num,0,-1)):
    print("Forward is %d, backward is %d."%(i, j))
```

another solution using zip (if you want use zip! but is slow):

```
test_num = 5
for i,j in zip(range(test_num), range(test_num, 0, -1)):
    print("Forward is %d, backward is %d."%(i, j))
```

**benchmarks:**

```
timeit.timeit('for i in range(5):pass', number=10000) # 0.004307041002903134
timeit.timeit('for i,j in enumerate(range(5,0,-1)): pass', number=10000) # 0.007563826999103185
timeit.timeit('for i,j in zip(range(5), range(5, 0, -1)): pass', number=10000) # 0.010275325999828056
```